# XML simpletype, simplecontent, complextype, complexcontent

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm having some confusion on the type  `simpletype`, `simplecontent`, `complextype` and `complexcontent`.

I'm almost new to **xsd**. Can someone help to clear the confusion that giving concrete examples.

Comment: Awesome chart https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/22/examples/schematree.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What is a Complex Element?**

A complex element is an XML element that contains other elements and/or attributes.
There are four kinds of complex elements:

1. empty elements
2. elements that contain only other elements
3. elements that contain only text
4. elements that contain both other elements and text

*Note: Each of these elements may contain attributes as well!*

**Examples of Complex Elements**

1. A complex XML element, "product", which is empty:

```
<product pid="1345"/>
```

2. A complex XML element, "employee", which contains only other elements:

```
<employee>
    <firstname>Deepam</firstname>
    <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
</employee>
```

3. A complex XML element, "food", which contains only text:

```
<food type="dessert">Chapati</food>
```

4. A complex XML element, "description", which contains both elements and text:

```
<description>
    It happened on <date lang="hindi">18.03.99</date> ....
</description>
```

Answer (score 49):

I know it's a bit late but I hope [this article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/08/22/easyschema.html) helps someone.

In short:

`<complexType>` and `<simpleType>` both define types. Complex types can have element descendants and attributes while simple types can't.

Complex types can have simple or complex content. Types with `<complexContent>` can contain child elements while those with `<simpleContent>` can only contain characters.

Answer (score 2):

**SimpleType** can only have value within the closing tag as follows:

```
<SimpleType>Antony</SimpleType>
```

*Whereas*

**ComplexType** can have children with attributes as follows:

```
<complexType name="xx">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="xx">
            <sequence>
                <element name="xx" type="xx" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another good [XSD tutorial](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-schema-tutorial/xsd-elements-attributes#simple-types) here.

Basically

xs:simpleType define a value type, this value can then be used within an element or attribute (so you could define an double with 2 decimal places or a string in the format of an IP address).

xs:complexTypes describe the structure of an element. It can define its textual value, its attributes and its child elements. The textual value and attribute values are described by xs:simpleType's.